# How to install nuget if its already installed as a nuget dependency, but its not visible from your project?

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a library that has a dependency on a nuget package. I installed my library as a nuget. The dependencies of the library has been installed to my project as well. Currently I see the nuget in my project, but i cant use it or reinstall it, cuz other nuget depends on it.

Question: How to install nuget if its already installed as a nuget dependency, but its not visible from my project?

Or: How to change the nuget visibility?

Comment: Do you use package references in the project file or do you have a packages.config file?

Comment: which command did you try for reinstalling?

Comment: I have a package config, and i have some references in my project... Actually one reference missing form the project that is inside the package config. So probably this is the key to my problem.

Comment: I mean there are references in my project file

Comment: Try update command to forcefully reinstall. Example - `Update-Package <package_name> -ProjectName MyProject -reinstall`

Comment: Ty, @as.if.i.code. It solved my problem.

Comment: I'm confused, why can't you use the package, what is stopping you? So you have ProjA the imports ProjB that imports ProjC right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force to reinstall nuget package with `Update-Package`. This should fix broken dependencies.

```
Update-Package <package_name> -ProjectName MyProject -reinstall
```